# iOS - how to move to a different page on click of a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I am an iOS development newbie. I want to go to another page (CountryViewController) from my current page (CityViewController) on the click of a button. How would I do that? Pardon me if this is a very beginner question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways. I assume you are using a UINavigationController. If so then you can create the VC and do this inside of your parent view controller.

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]
```

Answer (score 3):

So basically you are trying to build a multi-view app. There are many ways to do so. Bu I'll list 3 common ones -

1. `[self.view insertSubview:newViewController.view atIndex:3];`
2. Using [`UINavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
3. Finally using modalViewController - `[self presentModalViewController:newViewController animated:YES];`

In second method, I use this controller without `UINavigationTabBar`. Hide this navigationBar & provide custom buttons based on which `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated]` should occur.

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewController2 *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

set storyboard id in ViewController2 "Identity inspector".

Answer (score -1):

I have came across the same problem. While User logged in once need to redirect to different page or else need to stay in homepage by default.

**Here is the code snippet.**

Here

```
 N_loginmsg = @"success";
    NSString *N_loginmsg = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"remember_loginmsg"];
        NSString *storyboardId;
        if (N_loginmsg != nil && [N_loginmsg isEqual:@"Success"])
        {
            storyboardId = @"ListViewController";
        }
        else
        {
            storyboardId = @"HomeViewController";
        }
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];
        UINavigationController *mynav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:initViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = mynav;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```